# Filter inputs/data from a event (e) on google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have the following script that takes the inputs on Google Forms, makes a document with those inputs, and sends an e-mail with the document attached. It works properly, but I needed to filter some of the responses, but I don't know how to filter data in an event.

One of the questions on the forms is asking what kind of document people want:

[image]

Right now, I have only done the script for the 2nd option (Licença Especial em Pecúnia). I need to filter the data from the forms, so when I choose the 1st option (Substituição de Chefia) it generates a different document from a different template. Right now, the `function afterSubmit(e)` is triggered on form submit.

Excuse the portuguese names of vars and consts, the important ones for this questions I changed to english.

```
 function afterSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues; 
  const pdfFileLP = createPDFLP(info);

  const url = e.namedValues['Anexos ao ofício'][0];
  
  function getIdFromUrl(url) {return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}$/);};
  var idAnexo = getIdFromUrl(url);

  const nrof = e.namedValues['Numeração do ofício'][0];

  function pdfAnexado(idAnexo,nrof) {return DriveApp.getFileById(idAnexo).setName("Anexos do ofício of. " + nrof + "-PGE/PRF.pdf");};
  var pdfAnexo = pdfAnexado(idAnexo);

  eprotocolo(e.namedValues['Expresso do solicitante'][0],nrof,pdfFileLP,pdfAnexo);
}

function eprotocolo(email,ofi,pdfFileLP,pdfAnexo){

  var EmailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("mailLP");
  EmailTemp.mail = email;
  var htmlMessage = EmailTemp.evaluate().getContent();

  GmailApp.sendEmail("estag.pedron@pge.pr.gov.br","Of. " + ofi + "-PGE/PRF",
  "SEU EMAIL NÃO SUPORTA O FORMATO HTML, FAVOR RESPONDER ESTE E-MAIL PARA SOLUCIONAR O PROBLEMA OU ENTRAR EM CONTATO PELO TELEFONE (41)3281-6392.",{

    from: "procuradoriafuncional@gmail.com", name: "Gerador de ofícios da PRF", htmlBody: htmlMessage,
    replyTo: email, cc: email,
    attachments: [pdfFileLP, pdfAnexo]

  });


}

function createPDFLP(info) {
    
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1mgNPhM9f2U0BWrDK0FAfCYyq968rJ3E8");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1FfW3Jn9hHARpBU8t8szlQ2YwR9OPR1ZV");
  const templateChefia = DriveApp.getFileById("1qP3A8O27Ms8OuybaqrQ6jQBB_PQpo-RhDU9xjIw_a44");
  const templateLP = DriveApp.getFileById("1lRab5lPdbRcdl4gaI3zonFseE180cNu4-hWaovamerc");

  const newTempFileLP = templateLP.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDocLP = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFileLP.getId());
  const bodyLP = openDocLP.getBody();
  bodyLP.replaceText("{of}", info['Numeração do ofício'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{data}", info['Data do ofício'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{serv}", info['Nome completo'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{rg}", info['Número do RG'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{autos}", info['Numero dos autos'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{prazo}", info['Prazo'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{procurador}", info['Procurador solicitante'][0]);
  bodyLP.replaceText("{orgao}", info['GRHS de destino'][0]);
  openDocLP.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDFLP = newTempFileLP.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFileLP = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDFLP).setName("Of. " + info['Numeração do ofício'][0] + "-PGE/PRF.pdf");
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFileLP);
  return pdfFileLP;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was curious, I did a simple if statement at the end:

```
function createPDFLP(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1mgNPhM9f2U0BWrDK0FAfCYyq968rJ3E8");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1FfW3Jn9hHARpBU8t8szlQ2YwR9OPR1ZV");
  const templateChefia = DriveApp.getFileById("1qP3A8O27Ms8OuybaqrQ6jQBB_PQpo-RhDU9xjIw_a44");
  const templateLP = DriveApp.getFileById("1lRab5lPdbRcdl4gaI3zonFseE180cNu4-hWaovamerc");
  
  const tipo = info['Tipo de ofício'][0];

  if(tipo == "Licença Especial em Pecúnia"){
    const newTempFileLP = templateLP.makeCopy(tempFolder);

    const openDocLP = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFileLP.getId());
    const bodyLP = openDocLP.getBody();
    bodyLP.replaceText("{of}", info['Numeração do ofício'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{data}", info['Data do ofício'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{serv}", info['Nome completo'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{rg}", info['Número do RG'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{autos}", info['Numero dos autos'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{prazo}", info['Prazo'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{procurador}", info['Procurador solicitante'][0]);
    bodyLP.replaceText("{orgao}", info['GRHS de destino'][0]);
    openDocLP.saveAndClose();

    const blobPDFLP = newTempFileLP.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    const pdfFileLP = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDFLP).setName("Of. " + info['Numeração do ofício'][0] + "-PGE/PRF.pdf");
    tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFileLP);
    return pdfFileLP;
  } else if (tipo == "Substituição de Chefia") {
    const newTempFileSC = templateChefia.makeCopy(tempFolder);

    const openDocSC = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFileSC.getId());
    const bodySC = openDocSC.getBody();
    bodySC.replaceText("{of}", info['Numeração do ofício'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{data}", info['Data do ofício'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{servi}", info['Nome completo'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{rg}", info['Número do RG'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{autos}", info['Numero dos autos'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{prazo}", info['Prazo'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{procurador}", info['Procurador solicitante'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{orgao}", info['GRHS de destino'][0]);
    bodySC.replaceText("{periodo}", info['Período que o autor alega que ocupou cargo de chefia'][0]);
    openDocSC.saveAndClose();

    const blobPDFSC = newTempFileSC.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    const pdfFileLP = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDFSC).setName("Of. " + info['Numeração do ofício'][0] + "-PGE/PRF.pdf");
    tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFileSC);
    return pdfFileLP;

    }

  }
```